# How to have list of objects accessable to all classes in Java?

Tags: java

I'm writing a plugin for this server and I need to create a list of players which can be accessed by several classes.

For example, there will be three classes:

```
Events
Commands
Plugin
```

The 'events' class will have a list of players that are online as well as their context (I cannot add this context to the player).  I will need to access this list from all three of those classes.

I am unsure what to do, because I worry about the class loader messing with my things.

I've thought of making a global variable class with static accessor methods for the players and their context (thread safe) and just store everything I need to in here, but people say global variables are evil in Java and that this should not be done.

What should I do for this problem?

Comment: Just make another `PlayerList` class or something to hold the player list. It won't be a global variable since it's just another class that servers a specific purpose.

Comment: well, you could store them in a database, and have each class interact with a CRUD class that does lookups into the database....depends on how often you need to do a lookup, how fast it has to be etc. Personally I don't see a problem with the static object: never say never and never say always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a *singleton* class that contains the list that all the classes need to access, and then add that *singleton* as a *composite* member of all 3 classes.

The *singleton* design pattern is a *global variable* in a sense, but in an OO-friendly way that should work fine and not be *evil*.

Answer (score 1):

You can encapsulate your player list in any data structure (lets say class `Players` backed by a `Map` or `List` or whatever structure is needed) and pass a reference of that structure to the classes that needs it (`Commands`, `Plugins`, etc) either by constructor or setter.